# У кого то есть похожие табы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, вёрстка

Добрый вечер!
Может у кого то есть похожие табы с каруселью (не знаю как правильно называется)
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен!)

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ - Slider Syncing

Comment: @kizoso, тут скорее customPaging.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров да, тоже подойдет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow:3,
    arrows:false,
    dots:true,
    focusOnSelect:true,
    centerMode:true,
    variableWidth:true,
    customPaging: function(slider, i) {
          return $(slider.$slides[i]).find('.slide__title').text();
    }
  });
});

$('.slider').on('init reInit', function(){
  $(this).find('.slick-dots').prependTo(this);
});
```

```css
.slide{
  background-color:#ddd;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
}
.slick-dots .slick-active{
  font-weight:bold;
}
.slide.slick-current{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <h5 class="slide__title">Заголовок1</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <h5 class="slide__title">Заголовок2</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <h5 class="slide__title">Заголовок3</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <h5 class="slide__title">Заголовок4</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <h5 class="slide__title">Заголовок5</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true`

Comment: @HamSter , это да. Я просто основной принцип "табов" хотел показать.  Правку внёс.

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ ВАМ ЧЕЛОВЕЧЕСКОЕ СПАСИБО!)

Comment: Еще вопрос по ходу возник.
Как навигацию над слайдером сделать?

Comment: @Vladislav Chaly , внес правки в ответ. Хотя, возможно, это не самое изящное решение.

Comment: Главное что рабочее!)
Спасибо вам большое!